# Google API OAuth2: handle invalid token

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a tricky case while playing with OAuth2.

1. Starts by asking authentification to the user. He grants access, store the credentials in a store (DB, GAE Datastore, etc.).
2. Go to your Authorized Access in your Google's profile and revoke the
   app
3. Go back to the app, launch an action which leads to API call (tested
   with Drive API)
4. App is retrieving credentials from store. Test credentials validity
   (not null and invalid property is False)
5. Call the API
6. Retrieve a 401, Unauthorized exception.

How can I detect that the credentials are invalid BEFORE effectively calling the API?
Maybe it is the way to works with credentials?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What credentials are you storing? Access token? Refresh token?

Consider using the tokeninfo endpoint, https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=

Comment: I'm storing the Credentials object obtained when executing the OAuth step 2. According to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#step2_exchange) it contains both.

Comment: You can call tokeninfo for the validity of your access token, but if it's expired and you can retrieve a new one with your refresh token, there is no way to forecast.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the access_token, call [tokeninfo] in GoogleAPI first (always, if it's a fresh access_token even). I wasted some hours to solve this issue.
My workflow for a Windows application:

1. oAuth2 -> access_token* (* - not validated)
2. GoogleAPI.tokeninfo with [access_token*] -> "ok" or "invalid"
3. if "ok" - using for requested permissions